# How to limit app using wifi from shell

Tags: networking, firewall

The Android root firewalls didn't work on my android emulators, How can I limit app using wifi using shell?

Comment: Is your virtual device rooted? Try  the non root firewalls

Comment: It's rooted, non rooted firewall use vpns, and I run some vpn application myself.